# Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. login page not working

Tags: python, django, django-forms

i was stuck while creating login page  and getting error like  "Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted." please help me out of this

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from users.forms import UserRegisterForm

# Create your views here.
def register(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username=form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f"Account created for {username}")
            return redirect('app1-home')
    else:
        form=UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, "users/register.html",{"form":form})
```

**Urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from users import views as user_views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from app1 import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('app1.urls')),
    path('register/', user_views.register, name='register'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),
```

**Forms.py**

```
 from django import forms
    from django.contrib.auth.models import  User
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


    class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
        email=forms.EmailField()

        class Meta:
            model=User
            fields=["username", "email", "password1", "password2"]
**login.html**

{% extends "app1/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST" >
          {% csrf_token %}

            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Login</legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Login </button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="border-top pt-3">
            <small class="text-muted">
                Sign Up Here? <a class="ml-2" href="{%url "register" %}">Sign Up</a>
            </small>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

In setings.py file, I used to write

```
REDIRECT_LOGIN_URL = 'app1-home'
```

I am creating a blog with logins and logouts and registration. up to registration I am succeed after login page it will not redirect to index page

Comment: I think, you missed 'action' in form tag.

Comment: I got a solution just add registration folder add login.html in the registration  folder

Answer (score 0):

> You need to add below code snippet in your form, to enable csrf
>   verification in the django forms, see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/)

**Just like the below code :**

```
<form>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <anything_else>
</form>
```

Also, you have to use RequestContext(request) everytime you use `render_to_response` :

```
return render_to_response("login.html",
    {"registration_id":registration_id},
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And you have to import authenticate and login both :

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
```

I hope this helps...Thanks :)

Comment: by mistake it came